# Is there a way to tell Google that one of my pages isn't a soft 404?

Tags: seo, http-status-code-404, google-search-console

The page sitemap.php on my site constantly shows up as a soft 404 in Google Webmaster Tools. From my research, if I understand correctly, returning a 200 OK, but having text on your page that makes it seem like a "404" page can cause the soft 404 reporting.

On my sitemap page, the left column is a tree list of all the pages. However, on the right column I have the following text:

> Can't Find The Page You Want?
>
> Try looking through our list of website pages to help you find what you are looking for.
>
> Still not finding what you want? Why not try searching for it?

This text is followed by a search input field.

I would prefer to not have to change the wording on this page. Is there a way to let Googlebot know this isn't a soft 404 page? I have marked it as fixed many times, but it still keeps showing up.

Comment: You could tell robots.txt to disallow it.  Then it won't crawl it at all anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have given this thought, but I don't really want to stop Google from crawling it as it has links to all the pages of my site on it.

Comment: Do you have an actual valid 404 redirect in your .htaccess file?  I did a little looking around myself.  Other than Google knowing what your actual 404 page IS, there doesn't seem to be a solution, other than changing your wording...

Comment: Yes. In my .htaccess page I have `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php`

Comment: Then I'm afraid there is no other workaround.  Google implemented that thing, thinking it would clear some things up.  But sometimes pages that don't deserve it get caught in the trap.  The only thing I've seen that's helpful is to change the wording on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the text.‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌

**As a note to others who might find this in the future, updating my text has stopped Google Webmaster Tools from marking my sitemap page as a Soft 404**

### Original Text:

> Can't Find The Page You Want?
>
> Try looking through our list of website pages to help you find what you are looking for.
>
> Still not finding what you want? Why not try searching for it?"

### New Text:

> Find What You're Looking For, Fast!
>
> Use our sitemap page to help you quickly find the pages and content that you are looking for.
>
> If you tried using our sitemap, but still didn't find what you want, why not try searching for it?

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with the others here, there's nothing you can do except change the text.

If it's important to keep that wording then could you not create an image that contains the wording?